# Having trouble installing R package httpuv

Tags: r, httpuv

I am using R 3.3.3 on Debian/Linux 8 and I am having trouble installing the package httpuv, which is a dependency for another package I want to use. The installing error message is shown below. It seems like there are problems with libuv, but I am not sure about this.

How can I figure out where the problem is and how to fix it?

```
> install.packages("httpuv")
Installing package into ‘/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/httpuv_1.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 1758514 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘httpuv’ ...
** package ‘httpuv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -Ilibuv/include -pthread  -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/BH/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/later/include"   -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c RcppExports-legacy.cpp -o RcppExports-legacy.o
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -Ilibuv/include -pthread  -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/BH/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/later/include"   -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -Ilibuv/include -pthread  -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/BH/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/later/include"   -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c callback.cpp -o callback.o
g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -Ilibuv/include -pthread  -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/BH/include" -I"/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/later/include"   -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c callbackqueue.cpp -o callbackqueue.o
In file included from libuv/include/uv.h:62:0,
                 from thread.h:4,
                 from tqueue.h:7,
                 from callbackqueue.h:4,
                 from callbackqueue.cpp:1:
libuv/include/uv/unix.h:103:28: error: ‘sem_t’ does not name a type
 # define UV_PLATFORM_SEM_T sem_t
                            ^
libuv/include/uv/unix.h:135:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘UV_PLATFORM_SEM_T’
 typedef UV_PLATFORM_SEM_T uv_sem_t;
         ^
In file included from thread.h:4:0,
                 from tqueue.h:7,
                 from callbackqueue.h:4,
                 from callbackqueue.cpp:1:
libuv/include/uv.h:1562:27: error: ‘uv_sem_t’ was not declared in this scope
 UV_EXTERN int uv_sem_init(uv_sem_t* sem, unsigned int value);
                           ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1562:37: error: ‘sem’ was not declared in this scope
 UV_EXTERN int uv_sem_init(uv_sem_t* sem, unsigned int value);
                                     ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1562:42: error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’
 UV_EXTERN int uv_sem_init(uv_sem_t* sem, unsigned int value);
                                          ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1562:60: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 UV_EXTERN int uv_sem_init(uv_sem_t* sem, unsigned int value);
                                                            ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1563:31: error: variable or field ‘uv_sem_destroy’ declared void
 UV_EXTERN void uv_sem_destroy(uv_sem_t* sem);
                               ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1563:31: error: ‘uv_sem_t’ was not declared in this scope
libuv/include/uv.h:1563:41: error: ‘sem’ was not declared in this scope
 UV_EXTERN void uv_sem_destroy(uv_sem_t* sem);
                                         ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1564:28: error: variable or field ‘uv_sem_post’ declared void
 UV_EXTERN void uv_sem_post(uv_sem_t* sem);
                            ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1564:28: error: ‘uv_sem_t’ was not declared in this scope
libuv/include/uv.h:1564:38: error: ‘sem’ was not declared in this scope
 UV_EXTERN void uv_sem_post(uv_sem_t* sem);
                                      ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1565:28: error: variable or field ‘uv_sem_wait’ declared void
 UV_EXTERN void uv_sem_wait(uv_sem_t* sem);
                            ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1565:28: error: ‘uv_sem_t’ was not declared in this scope
libuv/include/uv.h:1565:38: error: ‘sem’ was not declared in this scope
 UV_EXTERN void uv_sem_wait(uv_sem_t* sem);
                                      ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1566:30: error: ‘uv_sem_t’ was not declared in this scope
 UV_EXTERN int uv_sem_trywait(uv_sem_t* sem);
                              ^
libuv/include/uv.h:1566:40: error: ‘sem’ was not declared in this scope
 UV_EXTERN int uv_sem_trywait(uv_sem_t* sem);
                                        ^
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:141: recipe for target 'callbackqueue.o' failed
make: *** [callbackqueue.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘httpuv’
* removing ‘/data/home/yh362/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/httpuv’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpqg62zZ/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("httpuv") :
  installation of package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: It's an interesting failure, I can't find the immediate cause. Perhaps you could open a new [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv/issues/new) for the package, and make sure to include the output from `sessionInfo()`, and the version of your compiler.

Comment: Try this in a terminal window instead... `sudo apt-get install r-cran-httpuv`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and tried several installations to make it work:

1. Install Java jre and jdk
2. Install **devtools** `install.packages("devtools")`
3. In the console, run `.libPaths()` to see where packages are installed.
4. Make sure to get full permission from your library directory
5. Run `devtools::install_github("rstudio/httpuv", lib = "directory from 3.")` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue. As you can see the error report:

```
    libuv/include/uv/unix.h:103:28: error: ‘sem_t’ does not name a type
    define UV_PLATFORM_SEM_T sem_t
```

After removing the semaphore.h in /usr/local/include, everything works.

You can see details in https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv/issues/110#issuecomment-371690583